# Laravel custom failed_jobs table for specific connection

Tags: php, laravel, queue, lumen

I'm in trouble with one issue... I'm not finding a way!

Basically, in my API layer I need to decouple the queues on 2 different databases in order to maintain the backups safely and independents.

For jobs queueing no issues, I resolved creating 2 different connection type in queue.php configuration file, but I'm not finding a way to customize the failed_jobs table... seems that it's necessary one, without particular configurations.

```
'connections' => [

        'database_custom' => [
            'connection' => 'mysql_custom',
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => env('QUEUE_TABLE', 'co_jobs'),
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
            // -- add here potentially configurations for custom failed jobs table????
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => env('QUEUE_TABLE', 'jobs'),
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Failed Queue Jobs
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | These options configure the behavior of failed queue job logging so you
    | can control which database and table are used to store the jobs that
    | have failed. You may change them to any database / table you wish.
    |
    */

    'failed' => [
        'database' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
        'table' => env('QUEUE_FAILED_TABLE', 'failed_jobs'),
    ],
```

Has anyone ever experienced the same problem?
Thank you in advance for your help.
Marco

I've tried a lot of possibilities, without any feasible outcome.

Answer (score 0):

To decouple the failed jobs table for two different databases, you can create a new database connection and specify the table name for the failed jobs.

Here's how you can modify the code to achieve this:

```
'connections' => [
'database_custom' => [
'connection' => 'mysql_custom',
'driver' => 'database',
'table' => env('QUEUE_TABLE', 'co_jobs'),
'queue' => 'default',
'retry_after' => 90,
],

    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => env('QUEUE_TABLE', 'jobs'),
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 90,
    ],

],

'failed' => [
'database_custom' => [
'connection' => 'mysql_custom',
'table' => env('QUEUE_FAILED_TABLE', 'co_failed_jobs'),
],

'database' => [
        'connection' => 'mysql',
        'table' => env('QUEUE_FAILED_TABLE', 'failed_jobs'),
    ],
],
```

by this idea, you have two separate failed jobs tables in two different databases, so you can maintain the backups safely and independently.

Answer (score 0):

In case of using several connections in your process you must specify in each action the connection name you want to use or if necessary define any other than the default.

1. Callback inside the function `boot()` of `AppServiceProvider`, **apply to all the Jobs**.

- Add uses

  ```
  use Queue;
  use Illuminate\Queue\Events\JobProcessed;
  ```
- Add Class Queue

  ```
   public function boot()
   {
       Queue::failing(function (JobFailed $event) {
           // $event->connection_name
           $event->database_custom; //in your case
       });
   }
  ```

2. The best, add the trait method `failed()` in your Job Class.

   ```
   public function handle()
   {
       //Your process
   }

   public function failed()
   {
      // $this->onConnection('connection_name');
      $this->onConnection('database_custom'); //in your case
   }
   ```

References: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#failed-job-events

... and sorry for my bad English